# submit <p> tag using summernotes

Tags: javascript, summernote

I am trying to submit multiple inputs whilst using summernote and airMode. Airmode does not work when attached to a "textarea" which is annoying. if it can please, please tell me. in the mean time i'm trying to hack so i submit the form and us PHP to add content to the DB.

i can submit a single "p" tag but i need to pass multiple fields. i need the "id" to remain ie $_POST[p][1], $_POST[p][2], $_POST[p][3] etc. if there is a better way please point me in the right direction.

```
<?php echo print_r($_POST[p]); ?>
<form id="form" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="postForm()">
<p class="inline-editor" id="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p class="inline-editor" id="2">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
<p class="inline-editor" id="3">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

<input name="" type="submit">
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.onsubmit = function()
  {
    var p = this.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];
    if (!document.getElementById('pval'))
    {
      var pinput = document.createElement('input');
      pinput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
      pinput.setAttribute('id', 'pval');
      pinput.setAttribute('name', 'p');
      this.appendChild(pinput);
    }

    document.getElementById('pval').value = p.innerHTML;

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Comment: I was using an old version of summernotes. update to fix issue. ie you can use textarea to submit form

Comment: php tag doesn't fit for this case. if you use jQuery then use it.s methods:

Answer (score 0):

Add multiple `input`-elements to your form, one for each `p`-element, and name them `p[1]`, `p[2]` etc:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var form = document.getElementById('form');
  form.onsubmit = function()
  {
    var pElems = this.getElementsByTagName('p');

    for(var i = 0; i < pElems.length; i++) {
        var p = pElems[i],
            id = p.id;

        if (!document.getElementById('pval_' + id))
        {
          var pinput = document.createElement('input');
          pinput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
          pinput.setAttribute('id', 'pval_' + id);
          pinput.setAttribute('name', 'p[' + id + ']');
          this.appendChild(pinput);
        }

        document.getElementById('pval_' + id).value = p.innerHTML;
    }

    return true;
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if summernote - bootstrap - jQuery
[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pj0oebvn/12/)

```
  $('form#form').on('submit', function(ev){
   console.log(ev);
    $('p').each(function(i, p_obj){
      console.log(p_obj);
      $('form#form').append('<input name="'+'pval'+i+'" type="hidden" value="'+p_obj.html()+'"  />');
    });
   //ev.preventDefault();
 });
```